# Append table cells to select boxes in indexed order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I am having a huge brain fart with efficiency right now.**

The idea here is if I have a static `table` (unfortunately formatted this way with the data I've received), how would I appropriately `append` a `select option dropdown` with every value from the table categorized easily?

I currently have it working, but it seems as if I could make it more efficient than my current statement. I have the feeling with all the `DOM` manipulation I have going on, if I tried to use this on a table with **thousands** of items it would lag the browser. Let's get to the code.

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z2V2p/1/

**HTML:**

```
<table id='data'>
    <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Value 1</td>
      <td>Prop 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Value 2</td>
      <td>Prop 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
      <td>Item 3</td>
      <td>Value 3</td>
      <td>Prop 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<select id="item"></select>
<select id="value"></select>
<select id="prop"></select>
```

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('tr td').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var select = '<option value="'+text+'">'+text+'</option>';
    switch($this.index()){
        case 0:
          $('#item').append(select);
          break;
        case 1:
          $('#value').append(select);
          break;
        case 2:
          $('#prop').append(select);
          break;
        default:
          alert('Unexpected Error.');
     }
});
```

---

**So, I suppose the questions are:**

- Is there any easy way to make this more efficient?
- Perhaps utilizing an `array` to cache the values, and `append` them
  from that?
- Or is there an easier method of using `index` of the items instead of
  my `switch case` that would render quicker and be more expandable for further `td`s if they were implemented?

I appreciate all of the help.

**I've considered just ultimately converting the darn table to a `json` object, but I figured I'd reach out here first.** *(this will deploy thousands of times per week, and I don't want anything hard coded.)*

**Looking for a way to add every `TD` in its `index` of its `TR` to be appended to an existing `select option` based on the `index` value.**

#### Basically re-categorize columns of `td` elements.

Answer (score 3):

First little thing: var names are important. So

```
var option = '<option value="'+text+'">'+text+'</option>';
```

Second and main. When we are making webapps with JS, the main perfomance rule is:

**Reduce access to DOM**

I tried you code with 15000 tr's in Firefox and Chrome. I wrapped you code with

```
console.time('DOM');
...
console.timeEnd('DOM');
```

Results was:

- Chrome - about 5000ms
- Firefox - about 20000ms

Then i replaced `$.append()` with just strings concatenation

```
console.time('String');
var itemOptions = '', valueOptions = '', propOptions = '';
$('tr td').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var option = '<option value="'+text+'">'+text+'</option>';
    switch($this.index()){
        case 0:
            itemOptions += option;
          break;
        case 1:
            valueOptions += option;
          break;
        case 2:
            propOptions += option;
          break;
        default:
          alert('Unexpected Error.');
     }
});
$('#item').append(itemOptions);
$('#value').append(valueOptions);
$('#prop').append(propOptions);
console.timeEnd('String');
```

Results:

- Chrome - about 1100ms (bravo, Chrome :))
- Firefox - about 4000ms

If you will change your data source to a JSON or something, next optimisation will not need, but you can set first argument of `.each()` method (index of all td elements) to avoid using `.index()`. I noticed about 300-500ms of speed increase. So the last version is

```
console.time('String');
var itemOptions = '', valueOptions = '', propOptions = '';
$('tr td').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var text = $this.text();
    var option = '<option value="'+text+'">'+text+'</option>';
    var modulo = index % 3;
    switch(modulo){
        case 0 :
            itemOptions += option;
          break;
        case 1:
            valueOptions += option;
          break;
        case 2:
            propOptions += option;
          break;
        default:
          alert('Unexpected Error.');
     }
});
$('#item').append(itemOptions);
$('#value').append(valueOptions);
$('#prop').append(propOptions);
console.timeEnd('String');
```

Results:

- Chrome - about 850ms
- Firefox - about 3500ms

Answer (score 2):

We can do some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/z2V2p/11/

```
<script>
    var dataArray = [];

    dataArray[0] = ['item','Item 1','Item2','Item3','Item4'];
    dataArray[1] = ['value','Value 1','Value 2','Value 3','Value 6','Value 5'];
    dataArray[2] = ['prop','Prop 1','Prop 2','Prop 3','Prop 6','Prop 5','Prop 6'];
</script>
```

by this way we will remove the table and now the dom will be happy :)
if you noticed the id of the select had been added to the array now we can remove the switch too by this code:

```
for(i=0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
    $select = $('#'+dataArray[i][0]);
    for(i2=1; i2 < dataArray[i].length; i2++){
        var option = '<option value="'+dataArray[i][i2]+'">'+dataArray[i][i2]+'</option>';
        $select.append(option);
    }
}
```

but now we have a problem with loop inside loop.

Comment: Well, the idea is to capture every item inside of a **500** 3 `td` (3 items) `table`. I don't want to hard code **500** values inside my code...

Comment: My point being, if I use a function to convert this table into different arrays, isn't that harder to accomplish than my code for the `client`? I mean, find `DOM` objects into `array`, then `parse` `array` into `DOM` seems like duplicate effort.

Comment: We might as well just $domObject = $domObject(converted) right...?

Comment: So what i understand now that we have:
formatted data as `table` > 3 `tr` > multiple `td` and we cannot change this format, are me right ?

Comment: Well, I'm happy to use this as it works in .42s when live with 40k items. I just like to expand. So, how can we make it .10 seconds by removing a step of DOM manipulation? **Answering your Q, pretend its 10,000 `tr` and all have 3 `td` items**. Its just an efficiency question, as I feel I could expand the `switch` case more manageable and expandable.

Comment: Sorry but i have another Q. Could we remove `table` from our code ?

Comment: and then get the data as `[]` or json

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12882/discussion-between-saad-shahd-and-nicholas-hazel)

Comment: Appeciate the offer, but `table` is the **use case**.

Comment: now i cannot do any thing and i wish to be there an answer to this Topic :)